# Implementing ASP.NET GridView complex display

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am writing a code where I need a GridView to display like as below, what I can do is display columns and its values to fetched from database for the columns but unable to present the data in this format.

My procedure gets one value as Total from DB to be displayed as Amount 1 and do the calculations with that amount to fill in other Amount values and to display the difference between two values as A:B

Any ideas?

```
--------------------------------------------
Total Amount |                 |           |       
--------------------------------------------
Amount 1     |    Amount/12 A  |           |
-------------------------------------------
Amount 2     |    Amount/12 B  |  A:B      |
-------------------------------------------
Amount 3     |    Amount/12 C  |  A:C      |
-------------------------------------------
Amount ..10  |    Amount/12 D  |  A:D      |
-------------------------------------------
Total        |                 |           |
--------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I can think of two ways to do this.

Either you go the ugly unintuitive asp.net way and add a handler for the grid's RowDataBound event. In that handler you would save the a value to a member variable if the member variable is empty. Else if the member variable is *unemtpy* you would do your calculation and add the difference as a new label in cell 3.

The other way (which I'd like more) you would project your list  (be that a datatable or other list) using linq into a new list of anonymous objects which has the properties of the original column plus a computed property for you extra column. Then you may databind the grid to your projected list.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, if it works for me, I will get back to you.

Comment: Hi, I have only one row which I fetch from the DB and do the rest of calculations. I have to use this row and iterate for 10 times and display the value in 3rd column. My question is how do I iterate the row for 10 times, I tried to use for loop in RowDataBound even but it would display only one row. What do you say?

Comment: I did not know this. If you already do calculate the extra rows I would suggest you put the calculation of the third column in that place, not in the onrowdatabound handler. If you show us some code we may come with suggestions...

Comment: there isn't any real calculation, what I do divide the value coming from DB which I consider a base value and divide it by 12 and add a percentage to it. 
Take the resultant value and again divide by 12 and add a percentage to it. I repeat it for 10 times to show 10 rows.

Comment: This is how I do it. `protected void premiumDueCalculationGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) { try { if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) { MonthlyFinancialReport records = e.Row.DataItem as MonthlyFinancialReport; PremiumDueCalculationGridViewRow row = new PremiumDueCalculationGridViewRow(e.Row); Master.IsAccessReadOnly); for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {row.Populate(records, Master.IsAccessReadOnly);} } } `

Comment: public void Populate(MonthlyFinancialReport records, bool readOnly)
            {
                _monthsDueTextBox.Text = "April Due"; 
                _preTotalLabel.Text = (records.Total / 12*0.15).ToString();
            }

Comment: if you see the monthsDue text box in populate method, I have to repeat this for April, May, June... 10 months.

Answer (score 0):

For that, you can use RowDataBound event. Below is the link to RowDataBound.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx

also read the solution in this thread.
http://forums.asp.net/t/1278588.aspx

Comment: Hi, it is not working for me, what I feel I create a table instead and place the records in it and seems working for me. Question here is, can I bind the data coming from stored proc to a table like we bind to datagrid? How?

Comment: For that you have to do your custom coding. I don't think there is any method available in ASP.NET for that. Still my advice will be to use GridView. It is much more powerful and much more stable.

Answer (score 0):

see if ur data is same in ur database

then u have a very simple solution by putting a div hold the content of the each row of gridview and give it a style for example color:blue; like this

Comment: Hi, I am calling a storedproc, which would give me only one column which would be my Amount, then I will compute this amount by dividing by 12 and so on get values for 3rd column.